# Call wrapped function with different arguments

Tags: python, refactoring

I am looking for a pythonic way to pass the expected list of arguments to a wrapped function. The problem is that the expected arguments differ by the function that is passed to the wrapper.

In my case, I want to refactor (repetitive) code that simulates multiple types of time series in a recursive manner. Except for the updating step in the for loop, the structure is (almost) identical. To this end, I decided to introduce a wrapper function `simulate` that takes the `update` function as an argument. However, the code becomes less readable because the arguments I need to pass to the `update` function differ across time series types. What would be a pythonic way to write this?

To illustrate the problem, I show how I generate a ramp and an autoregressive process separately.

```py
import numpy as np

def autoregressive_process():
    # magic numbers
    iT = 100
    lag = 1
    phi = 0.02

    # initialize
    vY = np.empty(iT)
    vX = np.random.rand(iT+lag)
    vEps = np.random.rand(iT)

    # generate observations
    for t in range(lag,iT):
        # updating step
        vY[t] = phi * vX[t-1] + vEps[t]

    return vY
```

```py
import numpy as np

def ramp_process():
    # magic numbers
    iT = 100

    # initialize
    vY = np.empty(iT)
    vEps = np.random.rand(iT)

    # generate observations
    for t in range(iT):
        # updating step
        vY[t] = (t % 10) + vEps[t]

    return vY
```

Note that, for example, the ramp process needs no `X` variable while the autoregressive process needs no time period.

Introducing the wrapper function looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np

def autoregressive(time, phi, X_lag, error):
    return phi * X_lag + error

def ramp(time, phi, X_lag, error):
    return (time % 10) + error

def simulate(update):
    # magic numbers
    iT = 100
    lag = 1
    phi = 0.02

    # initialize
    vY = np.empty(iT)
    vX = np.random.rand(iT+lag)
    vEps = np.random.rand(iT)

    # generate observations
    for t in range(iT):
        vY[t] = update(t, phi, vX[t-1], vEps[t])

    return vY
```

Note that I need to pass **all variables that would be necessary for both time series types** to the wrapped `update` function - even if they are not relevant.

Comment: above one look clean, easy and simple, no need to go second one as this increae complexity and will be harder to debug

Comment: The only thing I could think of to change is to pass the parameters as keyword arguments in your `update` function and use `autoregressive(phi, X_lag, error, **kwargs)` and `ramp(time, error, **kwargs)` to "filter out" the useless keywords, but that's ugly and doesn't achieve anything different. I would just stick to what you have now.